# php-cgi uses a different configuration than apache handler php

Tags: php, nginx, gd

I am using nginx with php-cgi and having some trouble getting imagettftext() to work.  I have just recompiled PHP with these options, however when using nginx and output phpinfo() I get that the build date was last month, and that `--with-gd` and `--with-freetype` aren't actually set in the configuration.

I wasn't aware that php-cgi and php used different builds/configuration files, but, if so, how can I remedy this?  Is there a way to make it use the same build?

I have tried editing php.ini but to no avail.

Edit:

The problem is the 'build commands'  given in the phpinfo() are completely different from each other.  Phpcgi shows 5.3.13 and with apache it shows 5.3.14..

Comment: You should use package system of your distro, and create own packages or use repositories. If you don't then you eventually will end with a binary mess that you have now.